# Intent.ACTION_CALL not working for API Level 25 and below

Tags: java, android, android-intent, permissions, build.gradle

I am pulling a phone number from the internet and placing a call on it directly. Now, when I use Intents to place a phone call, it works on all phones and emulators except for those at `API 25` or below. What could be a solution to the same?

Here is my manifest file permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Here is the code calling the Intent

```
public void callPhone(String phone){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

I have also set my `build.gradle` files accordingly

```
minSdkVersion 20
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

this is permission is also required